# What type of plastic band to use on a plastic bottle

Tags: design, user-preferences

This is a fairly theoretical question, but I'll try my best to explain it well. If I were a plastic water bottle designer and I were in charge of designing a bottle that stood out from other water bottles, would it be better to have a different shape to the water bottle as well as have a band on the water bottle that is longer than the standard two in or so inch wide band that is on most bottles today? Also, would the price be very different for manufacturing?

Comment: By band are you referring to the wrap that the label is on?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about this: http://www.officeprofiles.com/upload/products/large/378304.jpg

Comment: Versus this: http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r650/NoodlesToTea/IMG_1575_zps30edf715.jpg

Answer (score 4):

**It all depends on who your end user is in the water bottle market**. If you make your water bottle a different shape such as this:

[image]

**It may look cool a stand out from its competitors but loses functionality.** Could you imagine trying to go on a run and carrying one of these or putting it your bottle holder in your backpack on a hike?

**Same goes for longer labels.**

[image]

Which one looks like it would be easier to hang onto in a sporting situation with sweaty hands? The extended label covers up more real estate where you could provide grooves for gripping. But in turn you get more real estate for art and advertising.

so in the world of water bottles it all comes down to form versus function. If you want to make a more dramatic statement at the cost of functionality by all means make a larger label and different shape bottle.